# Verify and append to a package repository?

Tags: dpkg, apt-mirror

I have an ubuntu mirror set up and ready to be transferred by hard drive to an offline machine. I want to verify that the mirror has all the packages I need and add any missing packages to it. The mirror is located in `/var/spool/apt-mirror`, is 120 GB in size and has hundreds of .deb files in it. How do I do these two tasks?

(1) To check for a package to be present, I assume I have to use `dpkg` and point it somehow to my mirror and ask it whether my package in somewhere in the mirror. How do I do that? This is what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
dpkg --info /var/spool/apt-mirror/ astyle
dpkg-deb: error: error reading archive magic version number from file /var/spool/apt-mirror/: Is a directory
```

Maybe I should be using the `apt-cache` command somehow?

(2) Assuming that the package is missing, how do I get it into the mirror? Do I just find a deb file(s) and copy them wherever I want into the mirror "pool"? For example, lets say I want this package:

```
apt-cache showpkg astyle
Package: astyle
Versions:
2.01-1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
```

This package is apparently available in my local cache (but not installed on my staging machine). How would I move it into the mirror?

Comment: The first question to ask is how you generated and are managing your mirror. Some background would be helpful. What is the origin of your mirror, for example? Tools that manage apt repositories like `reprepro` automatically generate lists of packages which are required for apt repositories. The obvious next question is, do you have a master list of packages you expect to be in your repos, and if so, in what format? If you have such a package list, there's probably ways to compare it to the packages in your mirror without too much fuss.

Comment: I'm not really very familiar with reprepro and have no familiarity with other apt repos managing tools, so I can't give you detailed directions off the top of my head.

Comment: There are no weird 3rd party applications involved here. I created the mirror with apt-mirror (sudo apt-get install apt-mirror, then apt-mirror). Braindead simple. If you look at the paths I give in my question the methdology should be obvious because it says "/var/spool/mirror/apt-mirror" which is the default location for an apt-mirror repository.

Comment: Ok. Your repository might already have a top level Packages file. It sounds like you made a copy of some Ubuntu archive. Please specify the url.

Comment: Here's a sample of `Packages.gz`. http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz. Each of the sections in an apt repos have a corresponding Packages.gz file.

Comment: Also see https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.setup-apt-package-repository.html

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether a package exists somewhere in a directory tree, you don't need to use `dpkg`.  `find` will do, you're checking for the existence of a file - the fact that it's a `.deb` file is pretty much irrelevant.

e.g.

```
find /var/spool/apt-mirror/ -name 'astyle*.deb'
```

If you're planning on doing this repeatedly for many files, i'd recommend redirecting the output of `find /var/spool/apt-mirror/ -type f` to a file and then using `grep` to search that file - this will be much faster than running `find` once for each search.

If the package is missing from your mirror (and it exists in the repository that you are mirroring), check your `apt-mirror` configuration and run `apt-mirror` again.

To find out if the package is supposed to be in the mirror, `grep` for it in the relevant `Packages` file.  e.g. I have a mirror of the zfsonlinux archive for jessie, so if I wanted to find out if the `spl` package was supposed to be in that repo, I'd do something like:

```
# grep 'Package: spl$' /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.zfsonlinux.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages
Package: spl
```

or

```
# find /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.zfsonlinux.org/ -name 'Packages' -exec grep 'Package:\ spl$' {} +
/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.zfsonlinux.org/debian/dists/jessie-daily/main/binary-amd64/Packages:Package: spl
/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.zfsonlinux.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages:Package: spl
```

Comment: What if the missing package is not in a standard repository and has to be downloaded from Sourceforge or something?

Comment: in that case, why would you expect it to be in a mirror of a standard repository?  it obviously wouldn't be.  you'll have to handle files like that separately, perhaps by creating your own repository of miscellaneous programs/packages.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository and https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository to start with.